# Put Crystal Report calculation to Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have following question.

I have few oracle procedures(as example proc_1, proc_4), each one retrieves one rows with few columns.

I didn't put all procedures statement since they are big, just some example of first statement of procedures so you know, they are the same for proc_1 and proc_4:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_1 (
proc_1_cursor IN OUT Reports.rep_type,
date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN proc_1_cursor FOR
select * from -----
```

Then in Crystal Reports someone bult report and use result from these different procedures in CR formula:

```
if {?DATE_PARAMETER}>= DateTime (2012, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00)and {?DATE_PARAMETER}<= DateTime (2012, 12, 31, 00, 00, 00) then
({proc_1.DRY_GAS_MTD_KSM3}/1.07322+{proc_1.TOTAL_DRY_GAS_MTD_KNM3})+({proc_4.DRY_GAS_FLARE_MTD_KNM3})
else
if {?DATE_PARAMETER}>= DateTime (2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00)and {?DATE_PARAMETER}<= DateTime (2015, 12, 31, 00, 00, 00) then 
({proc_1.DRY_GAS_MTD_KSM3}/1.07322+{proc_1.TOTAL_DRY_GAS_MTD_KNM3})-({proc_4.DRY_GAS_FLARE_MTD_KNM3})
else
if {?DATE_PARAMETER}>= DateTime (2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00)and {?DATE_PARAMETER}<= DateTime (2016, 12, 31, 00, 00, 00) then
({proc_1.DRY_GAS_MTD_KSM3}/1.07322+{proc_1.TOTAL_DRY_GAS_MTD_KNM3})+({proc_4.DRY_GAS_FLARE_MTD_KNM3})-({proc_1.GAS_TO_LPG_M_MTD_KSM3})-
({proc_1.GAS_TO_T_FIELD_M_MTD_KSM3}/1.07322)})
```

What I want is to run Crystal Report calculation above in Oracle procedure that will call proc_1 and proc_4 procedures, so calculate in Oracle instead of calculating in CR and put to CR just end result,
can you help me with how this oracle procedure will like?

thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calc_proc (
date_parameter IN DATE,
gas_result OUT NUMBER)
IS
    dry_gas_mtd_ksm3 NUMBER;
    total_dry_gas_mtd_knm3 NUMBER;
    dry_gas_flare_mtd_knm3 NUMBER;
    gas_to_lpg_m_mtd_ksm3 NUMBER;
    gas_to_t_field_m_mtd_ksm3 NUMBER;

BEGIN

    dry_gas_mtd_ksm3 := proc_1.DRY_GAS_MTD_KSM3;
    total_dry_gas_mtd_knm3 := proc_1.TOTAL_DRY_GAS_MTD_KNM3;
    dry_gas_flare_mtd_knm3 := proc_4.DRY_GAS_FLARE_MTD_KNM3;

    IF (date_parameter >= TO_DATE('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND date_parameter <= TO_DATE('2012-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) THEN
        gas_result:=(dry_gas_mtd_ksm3/1.07322) + 
total_dry_gas_mtd_knm3 + dry_gas_flare_mtd_knm3;
    ELSIF (date_parameter >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND date_parameter <= TO_DATE('2015-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) THEN
        gas_result:=(dry_gas_mtd_ksm3/1.07322) + 
total_dry_gas_mtd_knm3 + dry_gas_flare_mtd_knm3;
    ELSIF (date_parameter >= TO_DATE('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND date_parameter <= TO_DATE('2016-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) THEN
        gas_result:=(dry_gas_mtd_ksm3/1.07322+total_dry_gas_mtd_knm3) 
+ dry_gas_flare_mtd_knm3 - gas_to_lpg_m_mtd_ksm3 -
        (gas_to_t_field_m_mtd_ksm3/1.07322);
    END IF;

END;
```

I've made a few assumptions, which might affect the stored procedure if you're able to clarify them:

- Your stored procs return a NUMBER value.
- Your stored procs match the format below.
- You don't need continuous date ranges in the IF statements.

Let me know if anything here is incorrect or I've missed something.

Comment: Hi bbrumm, thanks for code!! I tried it, it gives error message below: [Error] PLS-00225 (25: 48): PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'proc_1' reference is out of scope.  [Error] PLS-00225 (25: 48): PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'proc_4' reference is out of scope

Comment: Do you have a procedure called proc_1 and proc_4? Are they using the same schema? You might have to update the schema in the code above.

Comment: yea, they are in the same schema.

Comment: What are the parameters for these procedures? You may need to change the variable assignments to use the OUT parameters instead of the return.